# Selective HTML Decoding Problem

Tags: html

I have text in my DB that I want to display on the page. My DB content contains different  tags eg. `<html><b></b><help>` (because users are allowed to use any type of tags) etc.

When I display the content of the page, I want the `<br>` tags decoded into spaces whereas other tags should remain like ordinary text.

Please, how do I go about it?

Comment: assuming i have <b><go></come><p><br></p> in my db, i want only the <br> to appear as a line break while other tags should just appear the way they are on the browser

Comment: Appear as a line break, didn't you say in the OP you wanted it as a space?

Comment: im sorry was an error, wasntt wht i had in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$content = preg_replace('/<br\s?\/?>/', ' ', $content);

echo html_entity_decode($content);
```

If you want `<br>` converted to a space, and then all HTML displayed with their entities.

If I misinterpreted your question, and you *don't* want the HTML displayed with their equivalent entities, just skip the `html_entity_decode()` function.

### Update

Your comment to your OP now says you want the `<br>` to be a line break, so simply switch that second argument of `preg_replace()` from `' '` to `"\n"`.

### Update Again

Oh wait, I think I know what you want now. You want all tags to appear encoded, but the `<br>` to actually be a line break (i.e. not encoded)? Well if you do switch your `<br>` for `\n`, and you have no other line breaks, you could throw a quick and dirty `nl2br()` on the final markup.

### Update

Okay, just do this to get your encoded `<br>` back to a literal `<br>`.

```
echo str_replace('&lt;br&gt;', '<br>', $content);
```

Comment: mayb im nt too clear with my question:

while inserting into the db i use htmlentities($content).

while displaying, i want all <br> decoded and displaying other tags as just plain text tags

Comment: hmmm.. thanks so far:

i use the nl2br before inserting into the db.

Maybe i should use it while displaying the selected data from the db?

Comment: @alex - `<br class="reset" />`

Comment: @Stephen If he uses `nl2br()` on insertion into his database, it shouldn't be a problem. Of course, I wouldn't recommend inserting a encoded version into the database.

Comment: I agree, I *never* encode before inserting into the DB. I want to store *exactly* what the user typed. I encode/escape after retrieval and depending on the intended use; i.e. providing a JSON response needs to be escaped differently than dropping the text directly into HTML.

Comment: thanks stephen, alex and Gert... the prob is solved for all new post. I changed this: $text=htmlentities(trim(utf8_decodenl2br(($_POST["txt"])), ENT_NOQUOTES)); to: $text=nl2br(htmlentities(trim(utf8_decode($_POST["txt"])), ENT_NOQUOTES));
But i now have problems with previuos posts. they are now displaying <br> everywhere.